# how to decode std class object

Tags: php, mysql

i have a json stored in database which looks like this

```
[{"class":"button-input btn btn-warning","name":"gorilla-preview","value":"Goat","id":"gorilla-preview"}]
```

i'm retrieving it like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
          $array[] =  json_decode($row['element']);


      }
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($array);
```

its ouput looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [class] => button-input btn btn-warning
                    [name] => gorilla-preview
                    [value] => Goat
                    [id] => gorilla-preview
                )

        )

)
```

**my question is:** how to get all those value in a correct format?

Comment: What output are you expect?

Comment: simple `key=>value` pair array

Comment: Just set to `true` the second parameter of `json_encode()`

Comment: @Timurib  It wouldn't matter if he sets the 2nd Parameter to true or not so long as he is pushing all the decoded JSON Data again into another Array. He will always end up with a Multi-Dimensional Array which requires that he has to loop again through the `$array` Array anyways to get the Unique Values from the decoded Data. His interest is: ***.. how to get all those value...*** He needs to get the **VALUES of the elements within each decoded Data** irrespective of how they are accessed - whether as Objects or Arrays... Just a guess ;-)

Comment: change `json_decode($row['element']);` to `json_decode($row['element'], true);` that's enough

Comment: *"how to get all those value in a correct format?"* -- what is the correct format? Take a look at the documentation of the PHP function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). If you pass `TRUE` as its second argument it decodes the JSON string into arrays (as opposed to `stdClass` objects) and the arrays are usually easier to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to loop again because you are storing the decoded JSON Data in an Array. So, to fetch the unique values stored in the JSON Object you need a second loop like so:

> **NOTE:** From the Structure of your JSON Data, it seems much obvious that you need a nested Loop though...

```
    <?php

        foreach($array as $index=>$arrData){
            foreach($arrData as $key=>$objData){
                // DO SOMETHING WITH THE INTERNAL VALUES OF THE JSON DATA.
                var_dump($objData->class);
                var_dump($objData->name);
                var_dump($objData->value);
                var_dump($objData->id);
            }
        }
```

Alternatively, you may (*if you so wish*) skip storing the data in an Array and use it directly within the first loop like so:

```
    <?php

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $objData  =  json_decode($row['element'][0]);
            // DO SOMETHING WITH THE DATA LIKE BUILD A DYNAMICALLY GENERATED HTML STRING.
            echo "<p class='{$objData->class}' id='{$objData->id}'>{$objData->value}</p>;
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
If, according to your comment, you have a JSON Data like: `[{"class":"button-input btn btn-warning","name":"gorilla-preview","value":"Goat","id":"g‌​orilla-preview"}]` the snippet below *(which you may [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/698991))* shows how you may access your Data:

```
        $json       = '[{"class":"button-input btn btn-warning","name":"gorilla-preview","value":"Goat","id":"g‌​orilla-preview"}]';
        $arrData    =  json_decode($json);

        foreach($arrData as $key=>$objData){
            // DO SOMETHING WITH THE INTERNAL VALUES OF THE JSON DATA.
            var_dump($objData->class);      //<==YIELDS:: string 'button-input btn btn-warning' (length=28)
            var_dump($objData->name);       //<==YIELDS:: string 'gorilla-preview' (length=15)
            var_dump($objData->value);      //<==YIELDS:: string 'Goat' (length=4)
            var_dump($objData->id);         //<==YIELDS:: string 'g‌​orilla-preview' (length=21)
        }
```

Comment: your answer seems to be correct but level of nesting is what it has to determine right now i have implemented it but it is giving this error `trying to get the property of non object`  can you help me in this regard thanks

Comment: @DilipG   Could you check the updated Code? Not surprisingly enough though; you need a nested loop there as well.... ;-)

Comment: please don't feel bad as far as i know `json_decode()` converts the `json` into `php array`  so this my code `json_decode($row['element']);`  is converting `json` into `array` so why i'm unable to use  `->` like  `$objData->class`

Comment: do you have any other solution?

Comment: @DilipG  By default `json_decode()` converts JSON encoded Data to Standard `PHP Object` not Array. To get the Array type you have to explicitly set the 2nd Parameter to true.  Again, you are able to use the ***Object Access Notation ->*** if you didn't pass `true` as the 2nd Argument. And like the updated post hinted, you may need a nested Loop...

Comment: what you have told is correct but still i'm getting `trying to get the property of non object`  here is my test `json` `$json = [{"class":"button-input btn btn-warning","name":"gorilla-preview","value":"Goat","id":"gorilla-preview"}]` you check it yourself thanks again

Comment: @DilipG  Again check the updated code... for a quick-test, see: https://eval.in/698991

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
json_decode($row['element'], true);
```

When you need [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to return associated arrays instead of objects just pass true as second parameter.